# What framework should I use to build a web-based text annotation site?

Tags: drupal, frameworks

I know almost nothing about this sort of thing, so please forgive the newbie question.

I want to put together an open-source online literature annotation system. I hear this sort of thing is easier to do with frameworks like Drupal or Django, but I don't know very much about them. I found some Drupal plugins that handle text annotation. Is that the best way to go?

Oh by the way, if anyone is interested in contributing, please contact me, because I could use all the help I could get. I've been putting up ideas at http://hyperlit.tiddlyspace.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Annotator by Open Knowledge Foundation](http://okfn.org/projects/annotator/) might do what you want - used by OpenShakespeare...dual MIT/GPL, code is on Github, has a couchdb backend but you can develop your own storage since it is separate from the javascript annotation tool.

I have an idea to use drupal as a document repository and integrate okfn annotator but very much an idea, not a project (yet) - my particular use case is commenting on legislation/draft legislation.

For Drupal, these potentially might do what you want (in various states of development/functionality):

- [Open Review](https://github.com/patrickmj/Open-Review)
- [Yellow
  marker](https://github.com/clemens-tolboom/drupal-yellow-marker)
- [discussions on Marginalia but no
  movement](http://drupal.org/node/172517)
- Sticky Notes and other older modules did not fit my use case
  [ http://drupal.org/project/sticky_notes ]

EDIT: [Commentpress](http://www.futureofthebook.org/commentpress/) for wordpress might get you up and running quickly with limited features.

Comment: Thanks so much--these are awesome resources. I'm going to go explore these right now.